# insert data from one table into another with trigger in Oracle

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle19c

because of missing rights and lot of restrictions in our data warehouse I would like to use some dirty solution.
I have 2 tables

```
create table patrik_test (
marke varchar2(2)
)

create table patrik_test2 (
marke varchar2(2)
)
```

the first table should be refreshed with new data on daily basis. First the table will be truncated and then populated with new data.
the issue is that this is done in KNIME and as always the flow can fail due to timeout etc. but the table will be truncated at the beginning so this happens always.

We need to avoid the table with no data but there is no solution at this time so another one came up.
We can create another table patrik_test2 which will get data when new data in patrik_test get inserted.
So basically at the beginning both tables are blank.
When patrik_test gets truncated and afterwards populated with new data then table patrik_test2 should be truncated as well and get the new inserted data from patrik_test.

So we build a trigger like this

```
create or replace trigger patrik_test_trg
after insert on patrik_test for each row
declare
pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin

execute immediate 'truncate table  patrik_test2';
insert into patrik_test2
select * from patrik_test;
commit;


end
;
```

the issue is the table patrik_test2 gets truncated but will not be populated immediately.

```
insert into  patrik_test values ('AA');
```

patrik_test will be populated with AA but patrik_test2 not.

why and how to solve it?

if patrik_test fails in KNIME , so the table gets truncated but no data gets inserted the table patrik_test2 will remain with the same data so we have some tricky solution but at least the final table has some data all the time

Comment: Oh boy! The code you posted copies the entire content of `patrik_test` after every **RECORD** you insert in it. I am going to skip over how bad this will be for performance and just ask this: Can you perhaps explain how you expect this to be different from the very same trigger, but set to execute for each insert **statement**? TBH, I am not interested in the answer but I hope thinking about it will make you realize you should go back to the drawing board before starting the implementation.

Comment: @Atmo if I use statement level trigger it doesn't work either

Comment: Trying a statement level trigger was not where I wanted to lead you anyway... So at the end of the insert, you have 2 tables with the very same content, and the point of having twice the data is..?

Comment: @Atmo, there is Knime flow that truncate and populate table1 ,truncate occurs always but it could happen that inserting rows doesn't happen because there is timeout of the flow. Maybe slow connection etc will fail the flow so we get empty table. therefor a copy that will be updated just when the Knime flow doesn't fail.so this way you have table2 always with data, new or from previous run. this table will be used in another BI tool gor end user, one day old data is better as empty table. is dirty solution but we are at the end,we can not do lot of things in production database or Informatica

Answer (score 0):

`MERGE` the two tables (and do not use `FOR EACH ROW`):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER patrik_test_mrg_trg
  AFTER INSERT ON patrik_test
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO patrik_test2 dst
  USING patrik_test src
  ON (src.marke = dst.marke)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (marke) VALUES (src.marke);
END;
/
```

or, use a `PROCEDURE` and copy `patrik_test` and then rename the tables to make the copy `patrik_test2`:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE patrik_test_mv
IS
  has_rows PLS_INTEGER;
  TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST, -942);
BEGIN
  SELECT 1
  INTO   has_rows
  FROM   patrik_test
  WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE patrik_test_new AS SELECT * FROM patrik_test';
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE patrik_test_old';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN TABLE_DOES_NOT_EXIST THEN
      NULL;
  END;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE patrik_test2 RENAME TO patrik_test_old';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE patrik_test_new RENAME TO patrik_test2';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('patrik_test is empty!');
    RAISE;
END;
/
```

and run the procedure after loading data into `patrik_test`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F6hzZ4GQ)

Comment: I can not use procedure because it needs to be started manuelly in our enviroment and I want it automatically. The Trigger with Merge will not work because let assume we insert 2 values in patrik_test then we get this 2 values in patrik_test which is fine but next day the KNIME flow fails the table patrik_test will be empty. we still have 2 values in patrik_test which is correct but next time when patrik_test will be populated with anothe 3rd value then in patrik_test ist just this one value present and we want to have just this content in patrik_test2. it should be always a 1:1.

Comment: I consider to use the store procedure i side the Knime workflow to execude at the end but I get an ORA Error unsufficient priviledges at the line of first execute immediate statement. Not sure because the stored procedure is creted in the same user's schema as it will run the SP as well. So how can I have no priviladges if the creator runs own SP?